# SQL: Merge localized version of a table to the main one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have a main table like:

Table **guys**

```
|id|  name|profession|
|--|------|----------|
| 1|  John| developer|
| 2|  Mike|      boss|
| 3| Roger|   fireman|
| 4|   Bob| policeman|
```

I also have a localized version which is not complete (the boss is missing):

Table **guys_bg**

```
|id| name | profession|
|--|------|-----------|
| 1|  Джон|разработчик|
| 3|Роджър| пожарникар|
| 4|   Боб|    полицай|
```

I want to prioritize **guys_bg** results while still showing all the **guys** (The boss is still a guy, right?).

This is the desired result:

```
|id| name | profession|
|--|------|-----------|
| 1|  Джон|разработчик|
| 2|  Mike|       boss|
| 3|Роджър| пожарникар|
| 4|   Боб|    полицай|
```

Take into consideration that both tables may have a lot of (100+) columns so joining the tables and using `CASE` for every column will be very tedious.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `union all`:

```
select gb.*
from guys_bg gb
union all
select g.*
from guys g
where not exists (select 1 from guys_bg gb where gb.id = g.id);
```

Comment: Does that query need a order by id?

Comment: @Amit . . . If the OP cares about the order of the final result, then an `order by` should be used.

Comment: Thanks! BTW you've missed the alias for guys_bg in the first select ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it with using `FULL JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(b.id,g.id) id 
    , ISNULL(b.name, g.name) name
    , ISNULL(b.profession, g.profession) profession
FROM 
    guys g 
    FULL JOIN guys_bg b ON g.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!